# Protractor - Locating table elements using filter

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, filter, protractor

There are a couple of rows in a table and I need to click the edit link of row by matching the following text: `name1`

I cannot find 'edit' which is in the first row. I tried to locate the element using XPath and CSS but it didn't work.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="medication in modelCaseMed.medicationInfo" class="ng-scope odd" role="row">
  <td class="ng-binding">name1</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">04/06/2017</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">04/28/2017</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">12</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Hourly</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
  <td>
    <a href="" ng-click="addMedication(medication, 'edit')">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a> |  
    <a href="" ng-click="deleteMedication(medication, 'Modify')">
      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Can you please help me to match the text `name1` in rows and then click edit link of the first row?

Answer (score 1):

try the below code,

```
element.all(by.repeater("medication in modelCaseMed.medicationInfo")).filter(function(_tableRow){
  return _tableRow.element(by.css("td:nth-child(1)")).getText().then(function(name){
      return name == "name1"; //replace it with the required name;
  });
}).first().element(by.css("i.fa-pencil-square-o")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sudharsan, its working perfectly. 
can you please explain me about the css in two place 
1) 'element(by.css("td:nth-child(1)"))' -> what does 'nth-child()' does? in what places it can be used?
2) 'element(by.css("i.fa-pencil-square-o")' ->can we form css by merging tagname ? or this can be done only in special scenarios?

if you can provide me link which explains about these is also fine.
thanks a lot.

Comment: The above css will locate the first td tag present under each table row.

Comment: @HemaLatha consider accepting the answer if it helps to solve the problem!

Comment: Thanks Sudharsan.

Comment: i am facing one more issue, once i click on edit , on the same place 'Update' 'Cancel' is displayed. once i edit, i need to click on update. but the think is i am getting "more than one element found for the locator By(css.....)" because both Edit and Update are having same code

Comment: below is the code for edit and update, kindly help in clicking on update
`<td>
<div class="biometricActionCln ng-hide" ng-show="!list.isEditable" style="">
<a ng-click="editBiometrics(list, $index)">
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">
</i> Edit</a>
<span> | </span>
<div ng-show="list.isEditable" class="" style="">
<a ng-click="manageEditBiometric(editBiometric, 'Modify', list.biometricId)">
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">
</i> Update</a>
<span> | </span>
</div>
</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to get the `tr` using the text `name1` then locate the `anchor` using the text `Edit`:

```
var elmTR = element.all(by.cssContainingText('tr', 'name1')).last();
var elmEdit = elmTR.element(by.cssContatingText('a', 'Edit'));
elmEdit.click();
```